# Scalar Value from stored procedure via Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have found a few articles like this one:
http://devtoolshed.com/using-stored-procedures-entity-framework-scalar-return-values

Yet when I take the step to create a function import for a int32 scalar, this is what gets generated:

```
 public ObjectResult<Nullable<global::System.Int32>> MyStoredProcedure(Nullable<global::System.Int32> orderId)
    {
        ObjectParameter orderIdParameter;
        if (orderId.HasValue)
        {
            orderIdParameter = new ObjectParameter("OrderId", orderId);
        }
        else
        {
            orderIdParameter = new ObjectParameter("OrderId", typeof(global::System.Int32));
        }

        return base.ExecuteFunction<Nullable<global::System.Int32>>("MyStoredProcedure", orderIdParameter);
    }
```

I am able to call the procedure with this, but am not able to get to the underlying scalar:

`ObjectResult<int?> result = myEntities.MyProcedure(orderId);`

In the code examples I have seen, I should get `context.MyProcedure().SingleOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
int? result = myEntities.MyProcedure(orderId).FirstOrDefault();
```