# Stored Procedure returns incorrect scalar value of -1, instead of return value

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I am trying to return a scalar value from a stored procedure. I actually want to return the ID of a newly created record, but I have simplified my problem down to a stored procedure that takes an `int` and attempts to return that same `int`. This always returns -1. Thank you very much for your help.

Web API Controller call

```
var idtest = dbconn.my_return_int(123);
```

The stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_return_int]  
    @ID int  
AS  
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
    DECLARE @return as int

    SET @return = -999

RETURN @return
END
```

The `Context` generated stored procedure call

```
public virtual int my_return_int(Nullable<int> iD)  
{  
    var iDParameter = iD.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("ID", iD) :
        new ObjectParameter("ID", typeof(int));

    return (IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("my_return_int", iDParameter);  
}
```

Comment: Not sure this is possible in any sensible way... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405521/how-to-access-results-messages-and-return-value-of-a-stored-procedure-us

Comment: Thank you, DavidG for the article.  It got me started down the right path.  So what I did to solve this was change my Stored Procedure to return an ObjectResult<int?> instead of an int.  Then I did a SingleOrDefault() on the results of the Stored Procedure call, which yielded my int return value.  Here's the completed code.

Comment: Did you tried that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130661/why-is-entity-framework-calling-my-stored-procedure-but-returning-an-incorrect-v http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339750/entity-framework-stored-procedure-return-value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735477/get-return-value-from-stored-procedure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440896/stored-procedure-always-returning-0

Answer (score 7):

When you execute `ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction` the result is:

> [from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executefunction?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_Objects_ObjectContext_ExecuteFunction_System_String_System_Data_Objects_ObjectParameter___): discards any results returned from the function; and returns the number of rows affected by the execution

I.e. it doesn't return the output parameter, because it doesn't know there is one. Besides, as you have called `SET NOCOUNT ON;` in your stored procedure, it doesn't even return the number of affected rows, thus you get the -1.

So, you must do two changes:

1. change your procedure so that it doesn't return the value, but selects it, i.e. instead of `RETURN @return` do `SELECT @return AS alias`. NOTE that you need the "AS alias" part. The `alias` can be whatever column name you want.
2. change the mapping of the stored procedure, so that it expects an `int32` value. If you have doubt, refer to this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230773/scalar-value-from-stored-procedure-via-entity-framework).

In this way you'll read the return value as a result set, instead of a return value.

Comment: The included link to www.devtoolshed.com is forwarding to seemingly random sites.

Answer (score 6):

to solve this entity framework issue and assuming you already have a stored procedure working and you don't want to fix the places where it works good using other ways then EF you can replace the:

```
RETURN(0)
```

with:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT(0)
    RETURN(0)
END
```

that is if its a part of an IF sentence,
theמ go to: 
EF model (.edmx) -> Model Browser -> Function Imports -> (doubl click your func) ->Scalars -> Int32

now your return value is:

```
ObjectResult<Nullable<int>>
```

you can receive it by writing:

```
int? response = 0;
response = myEntity.myStoredProcedure(var1, var2).FirstOrDefault();
```

or in pics:
1.
[image: Model Browser]
2.
[image: Function Imports]
3.
[image: Scalars]

doing all this makes the EF model (.edmx) also supporting the 'Update Model from Database...' and you can update it without worry to changes you just made.

Comment: All sorts of this.  This is the only correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, DavidG for the article.  It got me started down the right path.  So what I did to solve this was change my Stored Procedure to return an `ObjectResult<int?>` instead of an `int`.  Then I did a `SingleOrDefault()` on the results of the Stored Procedure call, which yielded my `int` return value.   Like this:

Stored Proc:

```
-- RETURN @return does not work. Can't return a scalar value  
SELECT @return  -- This returns a result set with a single object that contains an int.
```

Then, my generated code looks like above but instead of returning an `int` it returns an `ObjectResult<int?>`

and I read the results like this:

```
var id = myDbContext.My_Return_Int(123).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just implemented another option in my project. I feed in another output parameter for @return.